# Wordpress Pass Strength indicator

Tags: wordpress, indicator

id="pass-strength-result"

How can you hide, the strength indicator,  using functions file o or through CSS?    I was able to customize every element of the login form using:

```
function stylized_login() {  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/stylized-login.css" />'; } add_action('login_head', 'stylized_login');
```

But the css showing the indicator box prevails.  It even adds an inline element:

```
'style="display: block;'
```

Which you can't eliminate even when you try to override it with "!important".

Comment: 'style="display: none;'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes css rules are added with specificity. A higher specificity means that lower specificity rules cannot overwrite even with !important. Inline styles are pretty high on this scale.

you add specificity by defining where your rule should apply. e.g. defining that it applies to a div with your class

```
 div.yourclass{}
```

or adding definitions of what the parents should be:

```
.parentclass .parentclass .parentclass #pass-strength-result{display: none;}
```

so to hide your element so that later applied styles do not override, look at the parent divs and construct your css like the above (try 1 parent class and so on).